# using the right class variable depending on the Class of the Object

Tags: ruby

I have the following classes:

```
class A
  @@one = {1 => "hen", 2 =>  "di", 3 =>  "tri", 4 =>  "tetra"}
  @@two = {5 =>  "penta", 6 =>  "hexa", 7 =>  "hepta", 
          8 =>  "octa", 9 =>  "nona"}

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    value = @value
    if value <=4
      @@one[value]
    else
      @@two[value]
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  @@one = {1 => "meth", 2 =>  "eth", 3 =>  "prop", 4 =>  "but"}

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end
```

and the following driver:

```
require_relative 'A.rb'
require_relative 'B.rb'

puts A.new(1)
puts B.new(1)
```

I would like the output to be:

```
hen
meth
```

but the A class variable @@one gets overwritten by B class variable @@one.  So my output is this:

```
meth
meth
```

I tried class instance variables, class constants, and class variables.  But neither solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this(since you said "I tried class instance variables, class constants, and class variables. But neither solution works."), i am giving a solution using class constants , best suited for this particular case:

```
class A
 ONE = {1 => "hen", 2 =>  "di", 3 =>  "tri", 4 =>  "tetra"}
 TWO = {5 =>  "penta", 6 =>  "hexa", 7 =>  "hepta", 
      8 =>  "octa", 9 =>  "nona"}

def initialize(value)
  @value = value
end

def to_s
 value = @value
  if value <=4
   self.class::ONE[value]
  else
   self.class::TWO[value]
end
end
```

end

```
class B < A
 ONE = {1 => "meth", 2 =>  "eth", 3 =>  "prop", 4 =>  "but"}

 def initialize(value)
  @value = value
 end
end
```

Explaintation: In such cases child case overrides stuff from parent class , so if you want to use someting from parent class(which is overridden by child class) you have to explicitly say that by class_name:: ("::" operator)

Comment: ok, thanks.  One question, why the `class` in `self.class::ONE[value]`?

Comment: `self` refers to the object this function is called on, `self.class` gives the class of that object.  when you did `puts A.new(1)` `self.class::ONE` was interpreted as `A::ONE`, when you did `puts B.new(1)` `self.class::ONE` was interpreted as `B::ONE`, i am not very sure if this what you wanted to ask ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class A
  class << self; attr_accessor :one end
  class << self; attr_accessor :two end

  @one = {1 => "hen", 2 =>  "di", 3 =>  "tri", 4 =>  "tetra"}
  @two = {5 =>  "penta", 6 =>  "hexa", 7 =>  "hepta", 8 =>  "octa", 9 =>  "nona"}

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end

  def to_s
    value = @value
    if value <=4
      self.class.one[value]
    else
      self.class.two[value]
    end
  end
end

class B < A
  @one = {1 => "meth", 2 =>  "eth", 3 =>  "prop", 4 =>  "but"}

  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end

puts A.new(1)
puts B.new(1)
```

A good article on this subject: http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/